# Draw diagram box in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image: output][image: thediagram]i am trying to draw those diagram as the attached picture but something is missing in my command i cannot put those boxes in right order as the picture, also i was trying to do the arrows in the double directions for example from a to b and from b to a but still shows only one way after compliation.
Here what i was trying.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\documentclass[handout,mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usepackage{beamerthemeDresden}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathrsfs }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage[ut8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,graphics}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{use=palette primary,fg=primary}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xspace}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, 
\usepackage{media9}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\definecolor{mynicegreen}{rgb}{102,252,102}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usetheme{upb}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size={}}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % besseren Umbruch
\usepackage{booktabs} % spezielle Tabellen zulassen
\usepackage{textpos}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamercolor*{title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg,}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-5bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]
%Information to be included in the title page:
\usecolortheme[rgb={0.7,0.2,0.2}]{structure}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{red!70}{yellow!85}

\mode<article>{
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
}

\mode<presentation>{
    \usetheme{Darmstadt}
}


\tikzset{block/.style={draw, thick, text width=1.8cm ,minimum height=1.5cm, align=center},   
    line/.style={-latex}     
}  
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}       
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \node[block] (a) {A};  
    \node[block,right=of a] (b) {B};   
    \node[block,right=of b, fill=blue] (c) {Algebre\\von\\Neumann};  
    \node[block,right=of a,fill=yellow] (b) {C*algebre\\ne\\comutative};    
    %\node[block,right=of d] (w) {W};   
    %\node[block,right=of e] (x) {X};
    \node[block,fill=red] (f) at ([yshift=-2.5cm]$(b)!1!(c)$) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative}; 
    \node[block,right=of c,fill=yellow] (g)at ([yshift=-3.5cm]$(d)!1!(e)$) {G};  
    \node[block,,right=of d,fill=red] (k) at ([yshift=-3.5cm]$(d)!1!(e)$) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative};     
    \node[block,,right=of k,fill=red] (l) at ([yshift=-3.5cm]$(d)!1!(e)$) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative};     
    \node[block,,right=of d,fill=red] (m) at ([yshift=-3.5cm]$(e)!1!(f)$) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative};     
    % the commands used for the different location of different blocks  
    %\node[block,fill=red] (b) at ([yshift=-4.5cm]$(b)!1!(c)$) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative};   
    %\node[block,fill=red] (d) at ([yshift=-4.5cm]$(d)!1!(c)$) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative}; 
    %\node[block,fill=orange] (c) at ([yshift=-4.5cm]$(c)!1!(d)$) {von\\Neumann};
    %\node[block,fill=orange] (h) at ([yshift=-4.5cm]$(h)!1!(f)$) {von\\ Neumann};   
    \node[block,fill=pink] (e) at ([yshift=-3.8cm]$(c)!1!(d)$) {$L^{\infty}(Y)$};
    
    
    %\node[block] (g) at ([yshift=2cm]$(c)!0.5!(d)$) {G};   
    %$\node[block] (h) at ([yshift=2cm]$(g)!1.0!(g)$) {H};   
    \draw[line] (a)-- (b);  
    \draw[line] (b)-- (a);  
    %\draw[line] (c)-- (d);  
    %\draw[line] (a)-- (e);
    %\draw[line] (g)-- (h);   
    %\draw[line] (d)-- (f);  
    %\draw[line] (e)-- (g);  
    %\draw[line] (f)-- (h);
    %\draw[line] (a.east) -- (e.west);  
    %\draw[line] (h)-- (b);  
    %\draw[line] (e.west) -- (a.east); 
    \node[draw,inner xsep=6mm,inner ysep=10mm,fit=(a),fill=green,label={90:$\mathcal{B}(H)$}](g){}; 
    \node[draw,inner xsep=2mm,inner ysep=2mm,fill=red,fit=(a)](g){};
    %\node[draw,inner xsep=4.5mm,inner ysep=4.55mm,fill=white,fit=(b)](g){};
    %\node[draw,inner xsep=2.5mm,inner ysep=2.5mm,fit=(d)](g){};
    %\node[draw,inner xsep=2.5mm,inner ysep=2.5mm,fill=blue,fit=(b)](g){};
    %\node[draw,inner xsep=2.5mm,inner ysep=2.5mm,fill=blue,fit=(a)](g){};
    %\node[draw,inner xsep=2.5mm,inner ysep=2.5mm,fit=(d)](g){}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In the attached picture is the diagram that i wish to draw it in beamer.
I APRECIATE ANY HELP.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, as it currently isn't. `ut8` is not a valid option of the `inputenc` package. You probably wanted to use `utf8` instead. (With a reasonably new installation, this is not neded any more since utf8 encoding is assumed by default) Apart from that, the definition of your `block` nodes, as well as `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` are missing, too.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: well, thanks I added them but the problem remains how to place them as I want in the picture attached there I am stuck.

Comment: Your example still does not compile properly. If I try to compile it, I end up with an error message such as " Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/block' and I am going to ignore it.". Before worrying about the placement of boxes in the "output" on a non-successful run, fix the errors. In general: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: i see, i am trying now to fix it, thank you for your help.

Comment: I repaired it now, you can compile it and you can see what I worked on and what came out of it and where I am stuck.

Comment: The node with `C*algebre\\ne\\comutative`, did you intend to name that `d` instead of `b`? After fixing some other errors, the first error I get that's related to the diagram is `! Package pgf Error: No shape named 'd' is known.`, indicating that no node named `d` exists.

Comment: If you compile the edited code it willl works, i will put it here again i do not know how to show you the output let me try to put another picture to show you the output.

Comment: Is this the output you're interested in?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFvrK.png

Comment: leandriis yessssssssss this is it! Can you show the code please?

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A place to start from:

[image]

Side note: I removed most of the preamble code since it was not at all related to the placement of blocks inside of the tizzpicture. You may want to take your time to clean up the preamble quite a bit, as well. There are quite some packages that are not needed in a `beamer`document (`graphicx`,...), as well as some conflicting/contradicting lines of code, especially regarding your beamer themes. I did not address these in my answer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, thick, text width=1.8cm ,minimum height=1.5cm, align=center},   
    line/.style={-latex}     
}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}       
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[block] (a) {}; 
    \node[draw,inner xsep=6mm,inner ysep=6mm,fit=(a),fill=green,label={90:$\mathcal{B}(H)$}](l-greenblock){};
    \node[draw,fill=red,fit=(a)](l-redblock){}; 
    \node[block,below=of l-redblock, fill=red] (l-c*algeb) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative};   
    \node[block,below=of l-c*algeb, fill=blue] (l-neumann) {Algebre\\von\\Neumann};   
    \draw[<->] (l-redblock)-- (l-c*algeb);  
    \draw[->] (l-neumann)-- (l-c*algeb);  

    \node[block, right= 2.5cm of a, label={90:$C(x)$}] (r-emptyblock) {}; 
    \node[block,right=of r-emptyblock, fill=red] (r-c*algeb) {C*algebre\\ne-\\comutative};   
    \node[block,below=of r-c*algeb, fill=blue] (r-neumann) {Algebre\\von\\Neumann}; 
    \node[block,below=of r-neumann, fill=pink] (r-infty) {$L^{\infty}(Y)$};  
    \draw[<->] (r-emptyblock)-- (r-c*algeb);  
    \draw[->] (r-neumann)-- (r-c*algeb); 
    \draw[<->] (r-neumann)-- (r-infty);
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, i try your code and it works. Now it make sense! I was trying a week ago everyday but it doesn't work! Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

As supplement to nice (+1) @leandriis answer. To his solution is added Ti*k*Z  libraries `backgrounds` and `chains`, for arrows head is used `arrows.meta` library, node placed by `fit` library is on background layer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                positioning}

\tikzset{
node distance = 7mm and 11mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {draw, thick, fill=#1,
                   text width=6.4em, minimum height=15mm,
                   align=center},
            > = {Latex},
   FIT/.style = {draw, inner sep=2mm, fill=green, fit=#1}
        }% end of tikzset

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
%% left branch
    \begin{scope}[nodes={box,on chain}]
\node (a) [box=orange]  {};
\node (b) [box=orange]  {C*algebre noncomutative};
\node (c) [box=blue!30] {Algebre von Neumann};
    \end{scope}
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node[FIT=(a), label=$\mathcal{B}(H)$] {};
% connections
    \draw[<->] (a) -- (b);
    \draw[->]  (c) -- (b);
%% right branch
\node (d) [box=white, right=of a, label=$C(x)$] {};
    \begin{scope}[nodes={box,on chain}]
\node (e) [box=orange,right=of d]   {C*algebre noncomutative};
\node (f) [box=blue!30]             {Algebre von Neumann};
\node (g) [box=pink]                {$L^{\infty}(Y)$};
    \end{scope}
% connections
    \draw[<->] (g) -- (f);
    \draw[->]  (f) -- (e);
    \draw[<->] (e) -- (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is also another option! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear @AngelinaMaria, policy of this site is that your thankfulness express by voting for answer which you like (by click on up-triangle at left top side of answer). Since now you have two answer you may consider to accept one of them (a one which the best fulfill your expectations).

Comment: Ok thank you, i vote now. Sorry i didn't know before.